# Angular -FormGroup set error on form-control does not update entire formGroup

Tags: angular, validation, error-handling, components, formgroups

I have Form Group with many form group and form-control as his children.

I have a case scenario where I need to update the form-control be be invalid manually - so I'm doing it using setError method as followinf:

```
setErrors({'incorrect': true});
```

This actually update the form-control and it's parent 
but not the entire Form Group.

Indeed there is method updateValueAndValidity().
which **By default, it will also update the value and validity of its ancestors,**
But doesn't recursively update the values and validity of the **descendants**

What is the best approach to set the entire formGroup as in valid ?

**Note** - My application is a dynamic form pages 
and in the component where I can set Error on the form-control
I don't have access to the entire Form-Group..
and I don't want to start moving up in the form-group tree and set each sub tree